# Can Exceptional Jordan Quantum mechanics model field theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, anticommutator

Exceptional Jordan Quantum mechanics is an interesting case in which observables are modelled with $3\times3$ Hermitian octonion matrices $\mathbb{J}_3(\mathbb{O})$. There is the [Jordan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_algebra) product $A\circ B = (AB+BA)/2$ which preserves Hermiticity. The [algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Jordan+algebra) is non-associative.

Now, although interesting, it appears that the degrees of Freedom in this model is precisely 27. Thus this model could model precisely 27 observables. (Perhaps the position of a single scalar particle in 27 dimensions).

I can't see how it would be possible to model more than one particle as the algebra seems to be finite dimensional. (Unlike the traditional algebra of $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices which can be infinite dimensional.

Thus, can we conclude that no Quantum Field Theory can be modelled using Exceptional Jordan Algebras?

Comment: There are “field theories” with finite numbers of dof, like TQFTs. But all physically relevant models of elementary particles are necessarily infinite-dimensional, so yes, your conclusion seems legit

Comment: Thanks prof. Any ideas why my question got downvoted? Well I know it's because it sounds like I'm advocating a crackpot theory instead of asking a legitimate question.

Comment: If you mention octonions it's an automatic downvote 

Comment: What I'm really wondering is if you can have a product of the exceptional Jordan algebra with an infinite algebra?

Comment: no idea actually, it may be a little naive (as in, two unrelated things don’t have to be connected), but it’s still a good question to ask IMO. Upvoted

Comment: All the cool kids downvote nowadays. Not sure what the deal is, it seemed like a reasonable question to me.